# Python Sequential Requests to .aspx page

Tags: python, asp.net, post, python-requests

Attempting & failing at rendering a page following a requests POST to an .aspx page. I have developed an alternative Selenium webdriver solution, but would like to understand why the post using Requests fails. I initiate a GET to collect the page parameters VIEWSTATE etc, then post with an 'Export type' checkbox selected. The html shows the page reloads with the news 'Data to Export' check boxes, however when POSTing with one of these check selected the default base url page is rendered. Any help in disseminating why the second post request is failing would be appreciated.The aim of the requests sequence is to download the 'Planned unavailability of generation' xml, between predefined dates.

```
import requests, csv, time, json, codecs
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, date
from io import BytesIO,TextIOWrapper
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess

def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')


url ='http://energieinfo.tennet.org/dataexport/exporteerdatacountry.aspx'

headers={

'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language':'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Host':'energieinfo.tennet.org',
'Origin':'http://energieinfo.tennet.org',
'Proxy-Connection':'keep-alive',
'Referer':'http://energieinfo.tennet.org/dataexport/exporteerdatacountry.aspx',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0'}

payload = {}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url=url)

headers['set-cookie'] = r.headers['set-cookie']

print (headers)
#headers['Content-Length'] = r.headers['Content-Length']

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
viewstate_tag = soup.find('input', attrs={"type" : "hidden", "name":"__VIEWSTATE"})
viewstategen_tag = soup.find('input', attrs={"type" : "hidden", "name":"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"})
eventvalidation_tag = soup.find('input', attrs={"type" : "hidden", "name":"__EVENTVALIDATION"})

payload[viewstate_tag['name']] = viewstate_tag['value']
payload[viewstategen_tag['name']] = viewstategen_tag['value']
payload[eventvalidation_tag['name']] = eventvalidation_tag['value']
payload['__EVENTTARGET'] =  'ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$rblSelection$3'
payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ''
payload['__LASTFOCUS'] = ''
payload['ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$rblSelection']= '3'
payload['ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$tbDateFrom']=''
payload['ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$tbDateUntil']=''

data = json.dumps(payload).encode()
#First POST request to load 'Data to Export' checkboxes - this bit works
r = s.post(url=url,data=payload,headers=headers)

#headers['Content-Length'] = r.headers['Content-Length']

with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
        f.write(r.text)

payload = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
viewstate_tag = soup.find('input', attrs={"type" : "hidden", "name":"__VIEWSTATE"})
viewstategen_tag = soup.find('input', attrs={"type" : "hidden", "name":"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"})
eventvalidation_tag = soup.find('input', attrs={"type" : "hidden", "name":"__EVENTVALIDATION"})

payload[viewstate_tag['name']] = viewstate_tag['value']
payload[viewstategen_tag['name']] = viewstategen_tag['value']
payload[eventvalidation_tag['name']] = eventvalidation_tag['value']
payload['__EVENTTARGET'] ='ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$cb_VNBProd'
payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ''
payload['__LASTFOCUS'] = ''
payload['ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$rblSelection']= '3'
payload['ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$cb_VNBProd']='on'
# payload['ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$tbDateFrom']='2012/01/01'
# payload['ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$tbDateUntil']='2018/01/01'
# payload['ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ExportData$btnSubmitDate']='Commit'

# for item , value in payload.items():
#     print(item,value)

data = json.dumps(payload).encode()
#Second POST request to load 'Planned unavailability of generation' checkboxes - this bit only returns the base url page

r = s.post(url=url,data=data,headers=headers)

with open("requests_results2.html", "w") as f:
        f.write(r.text)
```

Comment: There is javascript on that page which can not be executed by requests. E.g. clicking on one of the export type radio buttons causes new HTML to be downloaded from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of cookies looks suspicious.

When using a `requests.session`, you don't need to copy the cookies from the initial response to the following request(s) - they will be automatically sent. That is one of the functions of a session.

In any case the cookie is not being properly copied. The follow-up requests are supposed to re-present the cookie given by the server in the initial response, but your code tries to *set* a cookie by sending the `set-cookie` header. Instead it should be the `cookie` header, e.g.

```
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=cbxwegjj2jq1mwgr2ybdo0jj
```

But, as mentioned, `requests.session` will handle that for you.

Comment: I initially ran the request using `requests.session` alone, but this failed. I added the cookie statement out of dispair to try & find anywhere the request might be tripping up. Even if this is removed the second post fails...